# I don't understand this line in the code (simple code)

Tags: python

So I have this code (for decompressing a file) which I created from help of a friend:

```
wordsFile = open('wordsFile.txt', 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
words = words.split()

positionFile = open('positionFile.txt', 'r')
position = positionFile.read()
position = position.split()

position = [int(i) for i in position]

FinalSentence = []
for x in position:
        FinalSentence.append(words[x-1])   

print(' '.join(FinalSentence))
```

However I don't understand how the line `FinalSentence.append(words[x-1])` works in decompressing the positions and words back into a sentence. If anyone could explain in the simplest way possible because I am extremely new to this, that would be great :)

Comment: Please post code here as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Do **not** post links to images of code, or images of code. Copy and paste the code *into the question*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be sure since we don't have access to the files, but I assume that positions denotes the 1-index of the words' positions, but words is a 0-index array since that's how arrays work in python. So that's why you see x-1 instead of x.

So if your words file looks like

```
sentence this a is
```

And your positions file looks like

```
2 4 3 1
```

Then you would be appending **this**, **is**, **a**, **sentence** in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the files, I can only assume it does something like below (in it's simplest form obviously, because I couldn't see a real life scenario for the code below)

The positions variable is an array of integers.

It loops through the array of integers and minuses a value of one to get the array index for words.

For Example:

```
words = ['very', 'my', 'nice', 'sentence']
positions = [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

It then loops through the array of positions.

As it loops through the positions it does.

```
FinalSentence.append(words[2 - 1])
FinalSentence.append(words[1 - 1])
FinalSentence.append(words[3 - 1])
FinalSentence.append(words[4 - 1])
```

It most likely minuses 1 because array indexes start from 0.

You would then have:

```
FinalSentence = ['my', 'very', 'nice', 'sentence'];
```

Which then gets joined into

```
'my very nice sentence'
```

Answer (score 0):

These two make an array containing every whitespace-separated number in the "positionFile"

```
position = position.split()
position = [int(i) for i in position]
```

These three take each value from the list, and add the corresponding word from the "wordsFile" to a list of words.  *(The `-1` converts to 0-based indexing, as @purpleladydragons says)*.

```
FinalSentence = []
for x in position:
        FinalSentence.append(words[x-1])
```

This joins the words into a string separated with spaces, and prints it to the screen.

```
print(' '.join(FinalSentence))
```